# Splitting Lines, Mapping, and Merging to Text File In C#

Tags: c#, string, file-io, merge, split

For example, I have an **input text file "FILE1.txt"** that reads

```
000123400056780001324
000556700034520004758
```

Here, the first 7 numbers = item 1, the next = item 2 and so on.

And another **input map text file "MAPFILE.txt"** that reads

```
0003452 itema
0001324 itemb
0005567 itemc
0004758 itemd
```

Where lets say, column 1 are item numbers (7 chars) and column 2 is description (5 chars).

And a pre-existing text file in my project that I added so that I can write the output to it. Let's call it "OUTPUT.txt" -

`S.No    Item1    Desc1    Item2   Desc2     Item3  Desc3`

So ULTIMATELY, I need to get

```
S.No   Item1       Desc1      Item2      Desc2     Item3     Desc3

1      0001234     *          0005678    *         0001324   itemb
2      0005567     itemc      0003452    itema     0004758   itemd
```

I have around 100 lines like these. **How do I split FILE1 line by line and then map those item number substrings to the ones in MAPFILE and finally merge them into the OUTPUT.txt I've already added into my project?** I'm a beginner and I'm just starting out. I've broken my solution down into steps this way, but how do I go about this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add code where you tried to do it

Answer (score 1):

A Linq version is also possible

```
var mapping = File.ReadAllLines("MAPFILE.txt")
              .Select(line => line.Split())
              .Where(parts => parts.Length>1) //Skip empty lines
              .ToDictionary(parts => parts[0], parts => parts[1]);

var lines = File.ReadAllLines("FILE1.txt")
            .Where(line => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) //Skip empty lines
            .Select(line => string.Concat(
                                Regex.Matches(line, ".{7}")
                                .Cast<Match>()
                                .Select(m => m.Value)
                                .Select(s => s.PadLeft(10) + (mapping.ContainsKey(s) ? mapping[s] : "*").PadLeft(10))
                            )
             );


string finalResult = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0001234         *   0005678         *   0001324     itemb
0005567     itemc   0003452     itema   0004758     itemd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eser, I understood the code and used it as a base for my program. Also, how do I create a column in my output file that autogenerates the row number? And if the input file reads 01000123400005678, how do I split the "01" in the beginning to be like row number and then split the rest of the string as substrings of 7? I can see that the string.Concat(Regex.Matches) line has to be edited but it doesn't seem to take in an array entry...help me out please?

Comment: @neha To autogenerate row numbers you can use **`string finalResult = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.Select((line,num)=> string.Format("{0,-6} {1}",num+1,line)));`**   For the regex part try this code **`var parts = Regex.Matches("01000123400005678", @"(^\d\d|[^\^]{7})").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();`**

Comment: Thank you @Eser :) I used .Select((line, i) => (++i) + " " + String.Concat(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(line, ".{7}") and that did the job as well. Anyway, for that regex part, it's not just one entry like that...there are almost a hundred of them like "0100012340005678" "020001233000333" "0300023420002222" "04..." "05..." so on (the row number got mixed up in that string), how do I chop that out of the regex statement that reads the string in?